# Failing in convert a mnemonic to a seed for a solana wallet

Tags: node.js, blockchain, wallet, solana

I'm trying to use a wallet seed on the backend, using `nodejs`, to connect in blokchain. The `Keypair` module from ["@solana/web3.js"](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/) library has a `fromSeed` method, that I use with input from another method, from the [bip39](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bip39) library, that converts my mnemonic to a seed. This my code

```js
const mnemonic = <My-mnemonic>
console.log(bip39.validateMnemonic(mnemonic)) // true
bip39.mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic).then(buffer => Keypair.fromSeed(buffer)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This is my error

```sh
Error: bad seed size
    at Function.nacl.sign.keyPair.fromSeed (/home/diazrock/Carrera/Elasbit/NFT's/mint-nft-solana/node_modules/tweetnacl/nacl-fast.js:2329:11)
    at Function.fromSeed (/home/diazrock/Carrera/Elasbit/NFT's/mint-nft-solana/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/lib/index.cjs.js:5625:53)
    at bip39.mnemonicToSeed.then.buffer (repl:1:55)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Keypair.fromSeed()` takes a Unit8Array [check](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Keypair.html#:%7E:text=seed%3A-,Uint8Array,-seed%20byte%20array)

`buffer.toJSON().data` this returns a 64 length array, So this contains both the public key and private key respectively. Check [this](https://docs.rs/ed25519-dalek/1.0.1/ed25519_dalek/struct.Keypair.html)

```js
let a = new Uint8Array(buffer.toJSON().data.slice(0,32))
const key = Keypair.fromSeed(a);
```

I tried the above and this works.
`key` has a public key and private key component.